# command line BOX API redirect url

Tags: box-api

I want to write a PHP script to download files from box.com
but according the box API, I need to have a redirect url.

But I just want to download my files, I do not want to setup a webserver.

Any doc about download files from box.com without use a webserver?
I know the box Inc. offers a CLI tool, but I do not want to use it.